# Check a dynamic amount of properties in an array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to check a dynamic number of properties in an array of objects. I first thought of using an if statement, but then I figured the `.reduce()` function would be a better fit. My code currently looks like this

```
// example of how my data is set up
const columns: Array<{title, visible, property}> = [
    {title: 'hello', visible: true, property: 'prop1'}, 
    {title: 'Word', visible: false, property: 'prop2'},
    ...
];
const data: Array<{prop1, prop2, prop3}> = [];
const row: {prop1, prop2, prop3};

// the function I want to use to check which data matches a selected object.
customFunction(data, columns, row) {
   const validColumns = columns.filter(col => col.visible);

   return data.filter(d => {
      return validColumns.reduce((acc, column) => {
          return acc && d[column.property] === row[column.property]);
      });
   });
}
```

Is there a better/more angular way to check a dynamic list of properties on an element?

**Edit:** here is an example input/output

input:

```
const columns: Array<{title, visible, property}> = [
    {title: 'hello', visible: true, property: 'prop1'}, 
    {title: 'Word', visible: false, property: 'prop2'},
    {title: 'column 3', visible: true, property: 'prop3'},
    {title: 'column 4', visible: true, property: 'prop4'}
];

const data = [
    {prop1: '1a', prop2: '2c', prop3: '3a', prop4: '4a'},
    {prop1: '1a', prop2: '2d', prop3: '3a', prop4: '4a'},
    {prop1: '1b', prop2: '2c', prop3: '3a', prop4: '4a'},
    {prop1: '1b', prop2: '2c', prop3: '3b', prop4: '4a'},
];

const row = {prop1: '1a', prop2: '2d', prop3: '3a', prop4: '4a'};
```

Since `column` has `prop1`, `prop3`, and `prop4` as visible, it will check which of those props in `data` match those of the selected `row`

output:

```
const data = [
    {prop1: '1a', prop2: '2c', prop3: '3a', prop4: '4a'},
    {prop1: '1a', prop2: '2d', prop3: '3a', prop4: '4a'},
];
```

Comment: Better display an output example of what you are trying to achieve, so we can help you.

Comment: I added an example input/output

Comment: I think all you're missing is the initial value argument to `reduce`. Otherwise `acc` is undefined and is thus "falsy".